# Transferring pictures Android to Shotwell photos error issue

Tags: camera, shotwell

When I plug in my Samsung Galaxy A23 via usb and try to download pictures to Shotwell, I get the following error message: "The camera is locked by another application.  Please close any other application using the camera and try again."
This occurred AFTER I had successfully connected to Shotwell with the same camera.  Stumped.